# How to connect user with several parameters with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with Symfony (4.4) authentication. I want to make an authentication based on the email and the company of the user. This means that you can have several times the same email but with a different company.

I use the following guardAuthenticator for the connection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\Company;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppLoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'app_login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
        UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,
        CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
    ) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;

        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('_username'),
            'slug' => $request->get('slug'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $company = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['slug' => $credentials['slug']]);
        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'company' => $company]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return;

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE, ['slug' => $this->request->get('slug')]);
    }
}
```

If I do a `dump($user);` in `getUser` or a `dump($token, $providerKey);` in `onAuthenticationSuccess` I find the right user. But once the connection is over, when I arrive on another page I am connected with another user with the same email but in a different company.
I think the problem comes from the refresh user that has to be done only on the email, do you know how I can change that?

Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

You will add company on getcredentials() and use it on the get user function

Try this :

public function getCredentials(Request $request)
{

```
    $company = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Company::class)->findOneBy(['slug' => $request->get('slug')]);

    $credentials = [
        'email' => $request->request->get('_username'),
        'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
        'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        'company' => $company
    ];

    $request->getSession()->set(
        Security::LAST_USERNAME,
        $credentials['email']
    );

    return $credentials;
}

public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
{
    $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
    if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
        throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
    }

    $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email'], 'company' => $credentials['company']]);

    if (!$user) {
        // fail authentication with a custom error
        throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Hello Marwen ben alaya, it was a good idea, unfortunately it doesn't work.